# Ionic 4 - submit form with android keyboard “enter/go”

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Anyone knows how to make work a  submit with reactive form in android with enter/go key,i need to implement it on my login page but i tried (keypress.enter) and (ngSubmit) but dont work, this is my form

```html
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="ion-margin-top" (ngSubmit)="loginWithUser()">
                    <ion-row >
                        <ion-col size="12">
                                <ion-item lines="none">
                                    <ion-label position="floating">Email</ion-label>
                                    <ion-input formControlName="email" type="email"></ion-input>
                                </ion-item>
                        </ion-col>
                        <ion-col size="12">
                                <ion-item lines="none">
                                    <ion-label position="floating">Password</ion-label>
                                    <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password"></ion-input>
                                </ion-item>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                    <ion-row>
                        <ion-col>
                            <ion-button type="submit" (click)="loginWithUser()">
                                Login
                            </ion-button><br>
                        </ion-col>
                    </ion-row>
                </form>
```

ts file

```
    loginWithUser() {
console.log(this.loginForm.value)
}
```

any help is welcome

Comment: I understand that if you use (ngSubmit) -In angular is (submit), not (ngSubmit), but I don't know about ionic- you must not use (click) in the button submit

Comment: Perhaps you should open an issue to the [Ionic team](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues), I remember having the same issue in the past but it wasn't consistent across forms